# What is the proper voltage for each phase of a 3 phase system

Tags: three-phase, troubleshooting

So i was checking voltages of a 3 phase system, so i checked the voltage of each phase going into my breaker with reference to ground, but what i got is something weird

- A - GND : 50 VAC
- B - GND : 200 VAC
- C - GND : 160 VAC

Shouldnt it be somewhere in the range of 120VAC on each phase, can somebody tell me whats going on ?

If you need to know something about the system, just let me know and i can check it out

Comment: Sounds like your sub-station transformer secondary wye neutral point is not properly earthed. In the UK, 3 phase is 415 volts line-to-line.

Comment: `with reference to ground` Are you sure that this "ground" is earth? If it's not connected to earth properly then you can see any voltage w.r.t. that point.

Comment: Also Check the phase-to-phase voltages. To exclude some weird uneven loading going on. And by "GND", do you mean PE or N ?

Comment: @tobalt so you want me to measure  A-B , A -C , B-C. Correct right ?

Comment: Yes i would assumed this is protective earth since its connected the metal body of the breaker box, i do not know if its really connected to earth , i still have to trace it

Comment: Am i supposed to see a 4th wire (neutral) going to my breaker box ? Or is that on the electrical post only

Answer (score 1):

It is presumed that you are referring to a 3 x 208 V ~ 60 Hz utility supply.

The correct phase voltage should be 120 V as shown.

[image]

The root cause of your problem could be a broken neutral connection.